# openxlsx - fill row row based on text in another column

Tags: r, openxlsx

I am trying to fill a row in an excel workbook with `openxlsx` based on text in a column from that row. For example, if cell `C3` contains `A` then highlight row 3.

Ideally, this would not be `conditionalFormatting`. I would like it be the actual color of the row based on the text in a cell, but `conditionalFormatting` seems to be the only option. If I am able to make it the actual color, please let me know.

The code below shows that you can highlight a row based on the `value` of cell in that row, but not if you are trying to use text. In addition, if the `type` is set to `contains` then it does not seem to be accepting any styles.

```r
wb <- createWorkbook()

addWorksheet(wb, "Dependent on")
addWorksheet(wb, "containsText")


negStyle <- createStyle(fontColour = "#9C0006", bgFill = "#FFC7CE")
posStyle <- createStyle(fontColour = "#006100", bgFill = "#C6EFCE")


## highlight row based on value in column 2
writeData(wb, "Dependent on", data.frame(x = 1:10, y = runif(10)), startRow = 15)
conditionalFormatting(wb, "Dependent on", cols=1:2, rows=16:25, rule="$B16<0.5", style = negStyle)
conditionalFormatting(wb, "Dependent on", cols=1:2, rows=16:25, rule="$B16>=0.5", style = posStyle)


## cells containing text
fn <- function(x) paste(sample(LETTERS, 10), collapse = "-")
writeData(wb, "containsText", data.frame(letters = sapply(1:10, fn), numbers = 1:10))
conditionalFormatting(wb, "containsText", cols = 1:2, rows = 1:10, type = "contains", rule = "A")


openXL(wb) ## opens a temp version
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this the result you're expecting ?

```
library(openxlsx)


fn <- function(x) paste(sample(LETTERS, 10), collapse = "-")
a <- data.frame(letters = sapply(1:10, fn), numbers = 1:10)

wb <- createWorkbook()

addWorksheet(wb, "containsText")
writeData(wb = wb, sheet = "containsText", x = a)
color <- createStyle(fgFill = "#00CCFF") #BLUE
addStyle(wb = wb, sheet = "containsText", style = color, rows = which(grepl(a$letters, pattern = "A")) + 1, cols = 1)
saveWorkbook(wb = wb, file = "test_color.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
```

Comment: thanks! this looks promising but i have not had time to check it out yet.

Comment: this code highlights the first column blue, but not the row.

Comment: @Diego because in the function addStyle() I've set the parameter cols to 1 if you want it to highlight the entire rows you should replace it by 1:ncol(my_data) where my_data is your data frame

Comment: @Arkning. I am getting the correct rows highlighted, but not consistently (sometimes I only get part of the row highlighted). And other times I am getting the following error: `Error in addStyle(wb = wb, sheet = "containsText", style = color, rows = which(grepl(a$letters,  : 
  Length of rows and cols must be equal.`

Comment: @Diego I need to see your code in order to know why it doesn't work, so if you have some way i can easily contact you and see your code (in comments or create a topic on stackoverflow or discord, linkedin, etc...) let me know i'd be glad to help you !

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you're struggling with the fact that you want to apply conditional formatting to a column based on a value in a *different* column (which is a documented feature when `type = "expression"` but not when `type = "contains"`) but want that value to be text, not numeric.

Thankfully, though, the expressions allowed by `type = "expression"` can include text values! This won't work if you actually do need to conditionally highlight based on another column that *contains* text, but it will if you only need the other column to *exactly match* text.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(openxlsx)

# prepare test data
test_data <-
  mtcars %>%
  rownames_to_column() %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  select(rowname, cyl) %>%
  mutate(first_letter = substr(rowname, 1, 1))

# load the data into a few worksheets
test_wb <- createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(test_wb, 'by_number')
addWorksheet(test_wb, 'by_letter')
addWorksheet(test_wb, 'by_word')
writeData(test_wb, 'by_number', test_data)
writeData(test_wb, 'by_letter', test_data)
writeData(test_wb, 'by_word', test_data)

# create the test style
flagged_style <- createStyle(
  fontColour = '#274e13', bgFill = '#b6d7a8')
all_rows <- 2:(nrow(test_data) + 1)
```

[image: Test data based on the mtcars dataset]

Here are three examples:

1. Conditionally formatting rows based on the value of `cyl` (inequality)
2. Conditionally formatting rows based on the value of `first_letter` (equality)
3. Conditionally formatting rows based on the value of `rowname` (equality)

```r
# apply formatting...

# ... by numeric value (inqueality)
conditionalFormatting(test_wb, 'by_number',
  cols = 1:3, rows = all_rows, rule = '$B2<=6',
  style = flagged_style)

# ... by text equality (letter)
conditionalFormatting(test_wb, 'by_letter',
  cols = 1:3, rows = all_rows, rule = '$C2=="M"',
  style = flagged_style)

# ... by text equality (word)
conditionalFormatting(test_wb, 'by_word',
  cols = 1:3, rows = all_rows, rule = '$A2=="Merc 230"',
  style = flagged_style)

saveWorkbook(test_wb, 'test.xlsx')
```

Here're the results (I've pasted them next to each other):

[image]

If you do need a "contains" rule, rather than strict equality, you might need to use a dummy column. I don't think you'll be able to delete it after applying the formatting, unfortunately, as the conditional formatting is stored as a rule in the Excel workbook rather than being "baked in" when you `saveWorkbook()`.